# Removing duplicate values for order sequence numbers

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Hi guys a Simple question.

I got 3 columns 
A, B, C
with Name , Sku ,  order no .
Example : 
Daniel,    45785 , C2=if(A2>0, CONCATENATE("x",A2,TEXT(ROW(A1),"000")),"")

so "C2" combines the other two cells and give me an unique order number as "xDaniel001"

Now the problem is if Mr. Daniel enters 2-3 sku's, its will generate order number for each  entry as "xDaniel002 " and so on.

So how can i  Skip the order numbers if Daniel orders 2-3 In Column C
order number should be in sequence .

this is what the output should like

A , B , C

Daniel,    45785 , xDaniel001
Daniel ,   54852 , ( formula return  with no value  )
Asha,      54824 , xAsha002
Craig ,  24584 , XCraig003
Daniel ,  89784, ( formula return  with no value  )

All suggestions are welcome :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in C2:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(IF(LEN(A2:A)*(MATCH(A2:A,A2:A,0)=(ROW(A2:A)-1)),"x"&A2:A&TEXT(MATCH(A2:A,UNIQUE(A2:A),0),"000"),)))`

And with your qualification in comments, that a new ID must be produced on a new day:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A2:A)*(MMULT((ROW(A2:A)>TRANSPOSE(ROW(A2:A)))*(A2:A=TRANSPOSE(A2:A))*(B2:B=TRANSPOSE(B2:B)),SIGN(ROW(A2:A)))=0),"x"&B2:B&TEXT(MATCH(A2:A&CHAR(9)&B2:B,UNIQUE(A2:A&CHAR(9)&B2:B),0),"000"),))`

Comment: Brilliant, Thanks :) for that , Althought there seems to be one problem now :-o how do i validate against the Date, if Daniel needs another item tomorrow, it will get cancelled as well , as C2 lists for all cells in Column "c"

Comment: What if I insert Column 1 for date ,then Column B ,C & D As regular Name , Sku, order number . can i tell the formula , that  > hey any entries made today for "Name" will be one order number , and the sequence will follow .  


21/08/2014    Daniel    45845   XDaniel001<br>
21/08/2014    Daliel    54856   <br>
21/08/2014    Asha      54852    XAsha002<br>
22/08/2014    Daniel    98565    XDaniel003<br>
22/08/2014    Craig     54866    XCraig004<br>
22/08/2014    Craig     58741    <br>

Thanks